# Upload a file in folder using PHP script

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload and save an image using PHP scripting, but the image is not getting saved in the specified folder. Please help

here's my code:

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['button'])){
  $name= "product_name.jpg";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"],"student_images/$name");
  header("location: tryupload.php");
  }
  ?>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form action="tryupload.php" enctype="multiple/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Product Image</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button"/>
    </label></td>
  </tr></table>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

This part of your code `enctype="multiple/form-data"` is incorrect.

It needs to read as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Also make sure that the folder you intend on uploading to, has proper permissions to write to.

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php (setting folder/files permissions).

Uploading security-related links:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form
- [100% safe photo upload script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114147/100-safe-photo-upload-script)

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 1):

To upload multuple files you can have.

Multiupload.php

```
<? session_start()?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

    <title>Blank</title>

    <!-------Including jQuery from google------>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>



        <!-------Including CSS File------>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

    <body>
            <div id="formdiv">
                    <h1 class="uploadH2">Upload Your Artwork</h1>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

                  Take a photo, upload your artwork, or choose an image from Facebook or Instagram



            <label for="file">

                    <div id="image" style="margin-top:5%;">

                    <img src="img/camera.png">    

                    </div>

                    </label>



                    <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>


                    <input type="button" class="add_more" id="add_more" value="Add More Files"/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="img_upload" class="show-page-loading-msg" data-theme="b" data-textonly="false" data-textvisible="false" data-msgtext="" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"/>

                </form>

                <br/>

                <br/>

                <!-------Including PHP Script here------>

                <?php include "uploadScript.php"; ?>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

uploadScript.php

```
<?php
$dir_id = session_id(md5(uniqid()));
session_start($dir_id);
$path = "uploads/";
$dir = $path.$dir_id;
$path = $path.$dir_id."/";
if (file_exists($dir)) {
    system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
} else {
mkdir($path);
chmod($path, 0722);  
}
$_SESSION["id"] = $dir_id;
$_SESSION["directory"] = "/" . $dir;
$_SESSION["path_name"] = $path;
?>

<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image
    $target_path = $path;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">Only JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF files types allowed.</span><br/><br/>';
            }     
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This script will only accept, jpg, png, gif and jpeg. You can't upload or execute anything inside the directory unless you are owner and you can't have a file size bigger than 10KB.

script.js

```
var abc = 0; //Declaring and defining global increement variable

$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
                $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),        
                $("<br/><br/>")
                ));
    });

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file   
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                 abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

                var z = abc - 1;
                var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src='' style='width:40%; height:40%;'/></div>");

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                $(this).hide();
                $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'delete', src: 'x.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }));
            }
        });

//To preview image     
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    $('#upload').click(function(e) {
        var name = $(":file").val();
        if (!name)
        {
            alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        else {}

    });
});
```

This will upload multiple files, preview the image on the same page as the upload form, this will create a directory inside /uploads on the server with a directory matching the users session_id(). If the directory exists, the directory will be deleted, if it doesn't the directory will be created. The files will then be uploaded to that directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect enctype for the form. Instead of `"multiple/form-data"` use `"multipart/form-data"`.